# jQuery each() highest height, first one skipped

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to figure out why my first div of `.fullrow` is getting skipped. I don't have any index set and this is a WordPress/Advanced Custom Field (repeater) loop.

Does anyone have any suggestions I might try for this issue? I'm completely stuck as other ones I have set up are working fine. They only have one row instead of many. So, I can't figure out why it's working on only 1 row but skipping the first row on many.

http://jsfiddle.net/girdyshapiro/xezqmskk/

```
jQuery('.fullrow').each(function(){  

                            var highestBox = 0;
                            jQuery('#column', this).each(function(){

                            if(jQuery(this).height() > highestBox) 
                               highestBox = jQuery(this).height(); 
                            });  

                            jQuery('#column',this).height(highestBox);
                    });
```

Comment: Id must be unique use class="column" instead of id   and use jQuery('.column', this)  instead of jQuery('#column', this)

Comment: Oh Shoot! I can't believe I didn't see that before! I was completely staring RIGHT AT IT. Thanks so much for pointing it out! & Thank you so much for your super fast response.

Comment: never mind .. http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/xezqmskk/1/  .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have more than 1 of any #id on a page.

I have manually removed all the `id="column"` and added them to the `class` instead.

Here's the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wigster/5vor1ozb/